# How to clean corrupt SVG groups in QGIS SVG browser

Tags: qgis-3

how to clean corrupt svg groups  in QGIS svg browser:
(The upper 4 svg folder are empty)

[image]

**Update:** Here are the working , noncorrupt - collections stored in my windows 10 computer. I am using QGIS 3.28 and the corrupt SVG collections seem to be an old qgis-collections (qgis 2):
[image]

It looks like I can find it under settings-options-advanced, but whenI delete the old corrupt locations, QGIS does not accept this editing and "restores" the values.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, by default, the SVGs are placed under the user’s `QGIS` directory. At least that's the case if you use `QGIS Resource Sharing` plugin for importing your SVGs.

Comment: There are only the functional- not corrupt SVG-collections. see new screenshot in my question. I guess its somewhere in the registry?

Comment: I don't know. If these were custom made SVG then you are the only knows where they stored on your PC

Answer (score 0):

In our organization we store SVG symbols in *three* locations:

1. Users QGIS directory ("private" SVGs)
2. Network folder (organization-wide SVGs)
3. svg folder that comes with QGIS server-side installation

We observer the same behaviour wich significantly slows down working with SVG symbols.

Our solution is to clean up and re-create all search paths in a startup-script (if you are not familiar with this, read further at https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-python-code-when-qgis-starts), something like this:

```
QSettings().setValue('svg/searchPathsForSVG', [])

directories_conf = [
                    ('SVG-Symbole', 'list', r'X:\QGIS-Prog\svg', '/svg', 'searchPathsForSVG'),
                    ('SVG-Symbole Alkis', 'list', r'X:\QGIS-Prog\Plugins\alkisplugin\svg', '/svg', 'searchPathsForSVG'),
                    ('Print templates("Layouts")', 'list', r'X:\QGIS-Prog\layouts', '/core/Layout', 'searchPathsForTemplates'),
                    ('Project templates', 'list', r'X:\QGIS-Prog\project_templates', 'qgis/', 'projectTemplateDir'),
                    ('Processing scrips', 'text', r'X:\QGIS-Prog\script\processing', '/Processing/Configuration', 'SCRIPTS_FOLDERS'),
                    ('Processing models', 'text', r'X:\QGIS-Prog\script\models', '/Processing/Configuration', 'MODELS_FOLDER')]

empty_params = {'list':[],
                'text':''}

for topic, param_type, path, group, param in directories_conf:
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Updating folder for {} ...'.format(topic), 'Your organization', Qgis.Info)
    params = QgsSettings()
    params.beginGroup(group)
    existing_dir = params.value(param) #is string or list depending on parameter
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(existing_dir), 'Your organization', Qgis.Info)
    try:
        if existing_dir is None or existing_dir == [] or existing_dir == '':
            existing_dir = empty_params[param_type]
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('---> No folder for {}.'.format(topic), 'Your organization', Qgis.Info)
        else:
            if param_type == 'list':
                if isinstance(existing_dir, str):
                    existing_dir = [existing_dir]
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage('---> Current folders: {}'.format(str(existing_dir)), 'Your organization', Qgis.Info)

        if path not in existing_dir:
            if param_type == 'list':
                existing_dir.append(path)
            else:
                existing_dir += path if existing_dir =='' else (';' + path)

            params.setValue(param, existing_dir)
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('---> "{0}" Added to folder for {1}'.format(path, topic), 'Your organization',
                                     Qgis.Info)
        else:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('---> Folder "{}" already exists'.format(path), 'Your organization',
                                     Qgis.Info)
    except:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
            '---> Unable to set up folder for {}'.format(topic),
            'Your organization', Qgis.Info)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('... done.\n', 'v', Qgis.Info)
```

(replace or remove paths according to your needs)